# GpuArrayException: (b'', 12)

Tags: gpu, keras

I am simply trying to run through some recently posted LSTM tutorials on github, and I'm getting this error:

```
GpuArrayException: (b'', 12)
```

I have tried several tutorial examples and always get this same error, so I know it's not specific to one script.

I suspect the problem is that I am running Keras 1.2.2 (in order to follow along with Jeremy Howard's deep learning for coders class), whereas I think most folks are running Keras 2. Is there a good way to know what bits of code I need to convert? I find it confusing that I'm just getting GPU errors but not errors earlier on. I'd prefer not to have both versions of Keras on my computer, and I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: providing more information would be helpful. only from a small exception message, it is tough to find the problem. at least share the code snippet where you are encountering this problem. besides, which cuda, cudnn version you are using, are you using theano as backend - these information are useful to understand your problem clearly.

Comment: @WasiAhmad thanks for your information. I was trying to figure out what else to add and finally found something, which I've put above. I think this has something to do with Keras versions.